# How can I move validation summary on WFFM to display at the bottom of the form?

Tags: wffm, validation, mvc-forms

I'm trying to change the position of WFFM form validation summary in Sitecore 8.2 update 5. My form is very long and by default, the validation summary displays at the beginning of the form so the user is not aware that something went wrong if it fails because I do not scroll the page up. I found a file that seems to contain layout in \sitecore modules\Web\Web Forms for Marketers\Control\SitecoreSimpleFormAscx.ascx and I changed the position of validation in there but it doesn't seem to be using it - I can't see my change.

Is there any other file that is used as a layout for mvc forms?

Comment: You can always style it with CSS. It totally depends on the design.